# Откуда тут берётся null?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

AsyncTask

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (chararray != null)
            while (i < chararray.length )
                try {
            {charS = Character.toString(chararray[i]);

                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                broadcastIntent.setAction("PROCESS_RESPONSE");
                broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("text1", charS);
                context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                i++;}
```

Receiver

```
class RequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String PROCESS_RESPONSE = "PROCESS_RESPONSE";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String text1 = intent.getStringExtra("text1");
    TextView tv3 = (TextView) ((body)context).tv3;
    updateUI(text1, tv3);
}


private void updateUI(String text1, TextView tv3) {

    tv3.setText(tv3.getText() + text1);

}
}
```

Наблюдал процесс в отладчике. С массивом и строкой всё в порядке, но дальше откуда-то берётся Null

Comment: Хрустальный шар сломался. Где конкретно null?

Comment: Где хоть он берётся? А ещё лучше приложите стектрейс.

Comment: Походу, проблема в этой строке  context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent); . Честно говоря, не знаю, что должно быть вместо "context"

Comment: "context." удалите

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
tv3.setText(tv3.getText() + text1);
```

Должно быть что-то вроде:

```
CharSequence oldText = tv3.getText();
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(oldText)) {
    tv3.setText(text1);
} else {
    tv3.setText(oldText.toString() + text1);
}
```

Т.е. проблема в том, что изначально у вас в tv3 текст не задан, а вы пытаетесь null склеить с другим текстом.

Comment: Может попробовать `tv3.setText(""+tv3.getText() + text1);`

Comment: @Saidolim Ваш вариант не исправит проблему. При первом вызове это будет выглядеть как `tv3.setText("" + null + text1);`